# Using DotEnv in ReactJS app gives some error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, dotenv

[DotEnv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) is not working with ReactJS app.
I'm trying to use dotenv on my app but it's giving some [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vbdf.png)

`Project_Root/src/firebase.init.js`

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import 'dotenv/config'
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_apiKey,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_authDomain,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_projectId,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_storageBucket,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_messagingSenderId,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_appId
};
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
export { auth };
```

`Project_Root/.env`

```
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_apiKey="VALUE"
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_authDomain="VALUE"
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_projectId="VALUE"
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_storageBucket="VALUE"
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_messagingSenderId="VALUE"
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_appId="VALUE"
```

I've also tried by removing `import 'dotenv/config';` from `firebase.init.js` file and placing them on every file where I called `auth` but still not working.
If I comment out `import 'dotenv/config';` everything woks fine.

Packages

```
"dotenv": "^16.0.0",
"dotenv-webpack": "^7.1.0",
"firebase": "^9.6.11",
"react": "^18.1.0",
"react-bootstrap": "^2.3.1",
"react-dom": "^18.1.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
```

Comment: If you used create-react-app you don't need to use dotenv. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: you need to stop the dev server and run it again I think it's gonna work

Comment: @EisaRezaei already did